# Why is my picture not uploading?

Tags: html, css

I am developing a site for my school's robotics team and my banner picture will not show up for my main index file. It shows up for all of my others. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index_style.css">
<title>Team 3774 Homepage</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="Banner">
<img src="/Images/Banner.png" height="200" width="1350">
</div>

<div class="navbar">
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a class="li_nav" href="/Home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a class="li_nav" href="/Team Bio">Team Bio</a></li>
  <li><a class="li_nav" href="/Our Robot">Our Robot</a></li>
  <li><a class="li_nav" href="/Our Coach">Our Coach</a></li>
  <li><a class="li_nav" href="/Gallery">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a class="li_nav" href="/Outreach">Outreach</a></li>
  <li><a class="li_nav" href="/Youtube">Youtube</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Yes my file is in the proper folder and yes it is spelled right on the HTML code and in the folder. The site is robotichive3774.com if you want to take a look.

Comment: Be sure you're using correctly those uppercase letters. - Also, try with this `<img src="Images/Banner.png" height="200" width="1350">`

Comment: Spaces are most of the time a bad idea in URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show's up here. Also source has it referenced to /Banner.png instead of /Images/Banner.png

Comment: Maybe it is my computer. Thanks.

Comment: @Peleus did you click on the home link?

Comment: haha yes I incorrectly linked the home link to the website. It is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the path with "~", like:

```
  <img src="~/Images/Banner.png" height="200" width="1350">
```

This will include the path of the image from the root.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your page and your path is not correct:

```
<img src="Banner.png" height="200" width="1350">
```

Here is your Image:

http://robotichive3774.com/Gallery/Banner.png

But here it is not:

http://robotichive3774.com/Banner.png

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be fine. I think you need to reference the link to home to index or index. html though.

```
<li><a class="li_nav" href="/Home">index</a></li>
```

Also I would recomend you name all your files .html and include that in the links!

Hope that helps!